# Not getting a result from DB

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

So I'm checking to see if a user already liked a post. Here's what I'm doing

```
$id = 65;

//Get likes count
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM likes WHERE liked_post_id = :liked_post_id");
$stmt->bindValue(':liked_post_id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$return = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<pre>
<?php
print_r($return);
?>
</pre>
<?php

//Get user IP
$ip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];

//Check if user liked post
$result = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM likes WHERE liked_post_user = :username");
$result->bindParam(':username', $_SESSION['user']);
$result->execute();
$reprint = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $reprint['liked_post_user'];
$return_cnt =  count($reprint);

if($return_cnt < 1){
//Insert like
$query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO likes (liked_post_id, liked_post_user, liked_post_ip) VALUES (:usr_id, :user, :ip)");
$query->bindValue(':usr_id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':user', $_SESSION['user']);
$query->bindValue(':ip', $ip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
}
```

The problem is `$query` never gets ran. Even though I have no record of the username in the DB. So I'd expect it to run once, and insert `$query` into the DB, once. But it isn't. I'm not getting any errors either. Any ideas?

Comment: Since you're using `fetch` rather than `fetchAll`, `count($reprint)` is counting the number of columns in the row, not the number of rows returned. You should use `if ($reprint)`.

Comment: Are you sure your query has never run? Add some echo to last condition and check if it is displayed.

Comment: You're not checking whether the user liked a specific post. Your `SELECT` query is returning ALL the posts that the user liked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can simply count `$reprint`. To answer your second issue, you need to select the post, or else it'll simply check all the posts. So do

```
$result = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM likes WHERE liked_post_user = :username AND liked_post_id = :post_id");
$result->bindParam(':username', $_SESSION['user']);
$result->bindParam(':post_id', $_GET['id']);
$result->execute();
$reprint = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Note that if no user is logged in it'll still input an empty value. So make sure to figure a way around that.

Answer (score 0):

The second query should look for a specific `liked_post_id`. It's currently looking for *any* posts that the user liked, not just this one.

```
//Check if user liked post
$result = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM likes WHERE liked_post_user = :username AND liked_post_id = :id");
$result->bindParam(':username', $_SESSION['user']);
$result->bindParam(':id', $id);
$result->execute();
$reprint = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And then you should test whether the query found anything by testing whether `$reprint` is an array or `false`:

```
if ($reprint) {
    echo $reprint['liked_post_user'];
} else {
    //Insert like
    $query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO likes (liked_post_id, liked_post_user, liked_post_ip) VALUES (:usr_id, :user, :ip)");
    $query->bindValue(':usr_id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':user', $_SESSION['user']);
    $query->bindValue(':ip', $ip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
}
```

Comment: One more question. It only works with post id `65`. Whenever I try to change `$id`, no record gets inserted....

Comment: Should I post another post on SO then?

Comment: Maybe you should try to debug it first. Sprinkle `var_dump()` statements through the code, so you can see what's being returned by the queries.

Comment: Because if you post another question, you're going to have to provide relevant debugging details. Just posting a question where you change to `$id = 63` isn't going to be enough information for anyone to answer.